# Rails Asset Pipeline: How to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header when serving fonts in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, webfonts

The rails project that is serving these font assets is on a different domain than the project that is consuming it. In production, we will easily be able to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to Apache since Apache will be responsible for serving the static assets. However, in development, we have the same setup (dev.domain1.com and dev.domain2.com) except Rails is handling the serving of the font assets (I'm assuming).

How can I configure Rails to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for serving these assets in development mode?

Answer (score 1):

The answer turned out to be easier than I thought. If you were going to add this header in production, you would want to **enable the headers.mod** and configure Apache to set this header in the response:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

The solution to this in development is identical. The reason for this is even though Rails is serving the asset, Apache is still able to set the header.

Comment: It would be nice if you can state in your question that you use Apache on development environment as well, because it is not so common.